# Wordpress Orderby rand not working

Tags: php, wordpress

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
```

Can someone please explain to me why the `'orderby' => 'rand'` part is not working?

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Where are you using these arguments?

Comment: In my sidebar. It's to generate a random set of example logos. It works for all the other $args but not the 'rand' bit

Comment: Are you using it inside `wp_query()`?

Comment: No. I assumed that wouldn't matter as it works for all the other parts of the array.

Comment: Following the $args, I have $recent_posts = get_posts($args); foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ echo wp_get_attachment_image( $recent->ID, 'full' ); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I needed to add `'order' => 'post_date',` to the `$args`. Thanks @BenM  for your help!